# How do I automount usb drives in Linux (Debian)?

Tags: debian, usb, usb-drive, automounting

With every new release the way to automount USB drives in Linux seems to change (fortunately I'm using Debian, so I'm only losing a few days on this every 2 years). We used to have usbmount, udisks, udisks2, udisks-glue, pmount, custom udev rules, and I'm probably forgetting many more. (A quick look shows that at least a thing named `afuse` seems to exist, but is not documented too well). None of these work anymore (for me at least).

What is the "current" way to automount USB drives in Debian? I used the following `udev` rule, but since updating from stretch to buster this stopped working:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb-storage", ACTION=="add", \
RUN+="mkdir /media/usb%n; mount -o gid=plugdev,umask=002,fmask=111,users /dev/%k%n /media/usb%n"
```

Also: what is the stable solution to do this, that will reliably work even after updating to a new release, that I probably missed?

Answer (score 10):

You can create [`systemd.mount`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/systemd.mount.5.en.html) and [`systemd.automount`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd.automount.5.en.html) unit files. Here is an example:

To mount `/dev/sdb1` under `/mnt/mountpoint` , create a `mnt-mountpoint.mount` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mnt-mountpoint.mount
```

Note: The name of the unit file should be `dir-sub-dir.mount` extracted from the mount point `/dir/sub-dir`  (if you need to mount the device under `/media/mountpoint` the name will be `media-mountpoint.mount`)

Then paste the following lines:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Mount sdb1

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID_here
Where=/mnt/mountpoint
Type=auto
Options=defaults

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Use `blkid` to replace the `UUID_here` with the uuid of `/dev/sdb1`.

Create the `mnt-mountpoint.automount` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mnt-mountpoint.automount
```

To contain the following lines:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Automount usb

[Automount]
Where=/mnt/mountpoint

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Attach your USB then enable and start the units:

```bash
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable --now  mnt-mountpoint.mount mnt-mountpoint.automount
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is for mounting a particular device on a particular mount point (which can be solved by a litteral one-liner in `/etc/fstab`). My question was about how to automount generic USB devices in the smallest available /media/usb*N* directory.

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: Does this detect and mount when the USB is inserted, and automount when it detects the USB has been removed?

Comment: @semitones right.

Answer (score 8):

Update[2022-03-06]: Just `apt install udisks2` should give you usb automounting.

I researched (reverse) package dependencies in Debian of nautilus, udisks2 and libglib2.0-bin (which contains the gio binary). Based on this and on [Archlinux Udisks page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks#Mount_helpers) I now believe:

- The state of the art for the thing that actually does the mounting is udisks2. The next best thing to automounting is `udisksctl unmount -b /dev/$DEVICE`.
- On a "standard" Debian Gnome installation, nautilus is controlling the icons on the Desktop. When an USB drive gets plugged in, an icon gets shown for the drive but the drive only gets mounted on click on the icon.
- The best choice for minimal desktops for usb automounting is probably [udiskie](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie).

I added a user systemd service to start udiskie:

```
[Unit]
Description=Udiskie automount daemon

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/udiskie --verbose --use-udisks2 --automount --no-config --notify --tray --appindicator
```

Comment: This worked great for me. If you want to have the mounts user-accessible, add this "`[Service]
User=user
Group=plugdev`" above `ExecStart`. Also add a file "`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-udiskie.pkla`" with the contents: "`[udisks]
Identity=unix-group:plugdev
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.*
ResultAny=yes

[udisks2]
Identity=unix-group:plugdev
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.*
ResultAny=yes`"

Comment: Seems like the `--use-udisks2` option doesn't exist anymore, so it should be removed from the `ExecStart` command (tested on Ubuntu 21.10).

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happened to me after upgrade from Stretch to Buster (headless Raspberry Pi Zero W). In my case, I am using `/etc/fstab`, so systemd automatically generates mount units from it. All my disks are specified in fstab, and they were automatically mounted on hot plugin just fine in Stretch. It all stopped working in Buster. (The disks would mount fine on reboot, though.)

The culprit of the problem, it seems, was [the change](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/f53d56f1a3e6a9c7f9ef45c512f845d72ebb57e3/NEWS#L5039-L5045) in new systemd version:

> ```
>     * The .device units generated by systemd-fstab-generator and other
>       generators do not automatically pull in the corresponding .mount unit
>       as a Wants= dependency. This means that simply plugging in the device
>       will not cause the mount unit to be started automatically. But please
>       note that the mount unit may be started for other reasons, in
>       particular if it is part of local-fs.target, and any unit which
>       (transitively) depends on local-fs.target is started.
> ```

I verified it with `systemctl show my-mount.mount` command: the device was missing in the `WantedBy=` list, there was only `local-fs.target`. (While on Stretch there was `local-fs.target` and the correspondent `dev-sdaX.device`, both were listed.) As a result, when the disk was inserted, it did not trigger `my-mount.mount` unit to start.

So the solution which worked for me was creating the new udev rule that triggers `local-fs.target` each time the new disk is inserted:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/98-usb-disk-mount.rules 
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?[0-9]", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/bin/systemctl start local-fs.target"
```

(Note: the `systemctl start local-fs.target` command is recommended way to trigger fstab disks mount in [systemd manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.generator.html#Examples).)

Comment: Did 
<code>
# udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
</code>


Following

Comment: Ahh, sadly I need to remove this, see:

https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=773685#p773685

It caused boot to fail (fall back to emergency mode) due to being unable to mount /boot.

[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device <udev info for /boot >